# (Android) ¿Cómo puedo pasar variables de un fragment a una activity?

Tags: android

Simplemente necesito pasar unas variables de un fragment a una actividad al pulsar un botón, pero no sé cómo. Este es el onCreateView del fragmnt donde al pulsar el botón me debería llevar a la actividad y pasarle las variables:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info_crack, container, false);

        miTextViewInfoNombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewInfoNombre);
        miTextViewInfoFecha = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewInfocrackFecha);
        miTextViewInfoDescripcion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewInfoDescripcion);
        miImageViewInfoFoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewInfo);
        miFloatingButtonParticipar = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.floatingButtonParticipar);
        if(tipo.equals("Profesor")){
            miFloatingButtonParticipar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        miTextViewInfoNombre.setText(mi.getNombre());
        miTextViewInfoFecha.setText(mi.getMes() + "/" + mi.getAnio());
        miTextViewInfoDescripcion.setText(mi.getDescripcion());
        try {
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(mi.getImagen()).error(R.drawable.fondologin).into(miImageViewInfoFoto);
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            miImageViewInfoFoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.fondologin);
        }

        miFloatingButtonParticipar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar los datos desde este `Fragment` a una `Activity` puedes usar el mismo intent que usas para abrir la `Activity`, por ejemplo si deseas enviar el valor de `mi.getNombre()`

```
    miFloatingButtonParticipar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OtraActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("nombre", mi.getNombre());
             startActivity(intent);



        }
    });
```

la activity que lo recibe (En este ejemplo `OtraActivity`) tiene que recibir el texto enviado, puedes realizarlo dentro de `onCreate()`:

```
String nombre = getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre");
```